# Display div on certain pages

Tags: php, html

i'm having a problem with showing the facebook comment box on specified pages. I need a code to pull out the catagory from the URL and when the catagory is navigation_bar i need it not to show the facebook comment box. Also when i try it with the code below it only sees the closing     /div      and not the opening div class=...   , that messes up my entire template file.

URL example: index.php?categorie=navigatie_bar&onderwerp=startpagina

This is what the webpage shows: '};?>

Can someone please help me !

```
<div id="pagina_text">
    {{ CONTENT }}
    <br />
    <div class="rw-ui-container"></div>
    <br /><br />
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['categorie']) && $_GET['categorie'] != "navigatie_bar")
        {
            echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://alledaagsetips.nl"  data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';
        }
    ?>
</div> <!-- end pagina_text -->
```

Comment: give your url example

Comment: if you will enter just facebook comment div its works ?

Comment: In the code you have here, you are missing a `;` at the end of your `echo`

Comment: '{{ CONTENT }}' ?. If you are using template engine instead of normal php mixed html pages ? In that case check support for php code into template engine language.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` at the end of your `echo`, and you are checking for $_GET['categorie'] when the value in the url is `category`

**UPDATE** never mind that last part I see your edit

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope u have added facebook JS sdk at the top of your page,

can you please try the below code:

```
<?php $_GET['categorie'] ='test'; ?>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=587760987907604&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="pagina_text">
<br />
<div class="rw-ui-container"></div>
<br /><br />
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['categorie']) && $_GET['categorie'] != "navigatie_bar")
        {
            echo "<div class='fb-comments' data-href='http://alledaagsetips.nl'
                  data-numposts='10' data-colorscheme='light'></div>";
        }
?>
</div> <!-- end pagina_text -->
</body>
```

Comment: Yes i had. Because when i only put in the comment box code it shows on all pages. I will try your code now

Comment: The code doesn't work :( The problem is that the code onlt sees the closing div and not the opening so all my divs in the entire template are wrong :(

Comment: I checked the code and it is working for me.Please make sure your all your div's are properly closed